# Having troubles with SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am trying to modify a table within a database, as follows:

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO RamResults(Result, Date) VALUES(@num, @date)", con))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", num);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hostname2", hostname2);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Form1.date);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Although the table name has a variable prefix (hostname2). So I have tried to do the following:

```
("INSERT INTO @hostname2 + RamResults(Result, Date) VALUES(@num, @date)", con))
```

But no luck, anyone have any ideas to solve this?

**Error Message:**

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 13,Token in error = @hostname2 ]

Comment: You can't use a SQL parameter (i.e. `@`) for table names. And I'm not even going to suggest string concatenation to do the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, although it won't be suggested it is actually the only answer. However I agree with Yuck - the problem should be addressed from another angle. For example, why do you need dynamic table name prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use prepared statements like this, `@hostname2` will be replaced to `'value'`.
You should use `string.Format()` instead:

```
string hostprefix = 'host2_'; // example
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}RamResults(Result, Date) "+
                            " VALUES(@num, @date)", hostprefix);
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con))
// ....
```

BUT only use string.Format for your hostprefix, NOT for user input! This way you can prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

change the code like this:

```
new SqlCeCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0}RamResults (Result, Date) VALUES(@num, @date)", hostname2), con))
```

then do not pass/set the @hostname2 parameter anymore. SQL Parameters are not same as dynamic SQL generation...

Answer (score 0):

You can't vary table names with parameters. For that part, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in "normal" SQL the name of the table to insert into can not be parameterized.